# Meaning of 这道题其他很容易

Tags: grammar

I was going through the grammar points for HSK 3 and I found this sentences. I understand (or so I think) every words but I still don't understand the sentence structure.

这道题：this issue/problem/question/etc.
其他：other
很容易：(very) easy

In other examples I found 其他 is placed before the noun which it refers to, as in English. For example: 除了看书，他还有很多其他爱好。(http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/entry/5f5af2c4bcd04bf79ff36504df0d8fdb)

Is there another meaning to 其他 in this sentence?

Thanks,
Norbert

Comment: I think it should be 这道题其实很容易.

Comment: Wow, I spent more than an hour trying to figure this out. It didn't even occur to me that I may have typed in the wrong character from my paper. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

其他 should be a typo of 其实, which means *actually*.